# Why is AutoMapper mapping an integer field to an object?

Tags: c#, automapper

I've run into an issue today that I just can't figure out.  Automapper is mapping an integer field to an object field without me telling it to do so.

Here are my very stripped down relevant classes that reproduce the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperRepositoryProfile>());
        var combatant = new Infrastructure.PersistenceModels.Combatant()
        {
            Id = 2,
        };
        var mapped = Mapper.Map<Guy>(combatant);
        // Creates an object with
        // Id = 2
        // abilityStage = {
        //                   Id = 5,
        //                   Name = null
        //                }
    }
}

//Source
public class Combatant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int abilitystageId { get; set; } = 5;
}

//destination
public class Guy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AbilityStage abilityStage { get; set; }
}

//PersistenceModels (Source class)
public class AbilityStage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Destination class
public class AbilityStage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AutoMapperRepositoryProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperRepositoryProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CombatArena.Core.Entities.AbilityStage, CombatArena.Infrastructure.PersistenceModels.AbilityStage>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CombatArena.Core.Entities.Guy, CombatArena.Infrastructure.PersistenceModels.Combatant>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Somehow, this is creating an object such that "mapped" has an Id of 2, with an "abilityStage" that has an Id of 5 and a null Name.  What I want to happen is for "mapped" to have an Id of 5 and an "abilityStage" that is null.

Very importantly, if I change Combatant's "abilitystageId" property name to something slightly different (a_abilityStageId, abilityStageId_, etc), I don't observe this behavior.  It seems to be caused by the fact that the field has the same name as a destination class field, but with Id on the end of it.  I tried to reproduce this in a new project from scratch and it's not happening there, so I'm just at a loss as to what is causing this.

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this, and if there is a clean way to turn this behavior off?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks, didn't come across that in my googling